# Get the SQL Exception message from DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Working on an api call which alters some data in DB.I am trying to provide a meaningful message from api in case there is an exception in JPA Layer. On any sql query run failure I get DataIntegrityViolationException from JPA which does not contain the exact reason of failure. Hence I am extracting the SQLException from it and then responding with the error message.

```
private String getSQLExceptionMessage(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    Throwable nextException = e.getCause();
    while (!nextException.getClass().equals(SQLException.class) && nextException.getCause() != null
            && !nextException.getClass().equals(nextException.getCause().getClass())) {
        nextException = nextException.getCause();
    }
    return nextException.getMessage();
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How do you plan to handle failure in your API? Throw the original exceptions, wrap them in your own exception type, ... ?

Comment: I have a list of error field in response, I was thinking to respond with 500 status code and fill in the error field with the list of messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an utility class `NestedExceptionUtils` in Spring, which `getMostSpecificCause` method you can use to get the 'root' cause of any exception.

Regarding the error handling - you can implement a [custom exception handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes) for `DataIntegrityViolationException`, extract the constraint name from the root cause, analyze it and create a corresponding message for the user.

Some error handling examples: [1](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling), [2](https://github.com/Cepr0/single-file-app).

Comment: The problem with using `NestedExceptionUtils.getMostSpecificCause` is that it is giving the me the last `SQLException` in the `getCause()` chain which does not have the proper error message. However the first `SQLException` in the `getCause()` chain has the correct root cause message.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use `NestedExceptionUtils` in Spring to get root course for any exception. Sample code below

```
 try {
          //your code
    
      } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
          throw new DataIntegrityViolationException(NestedExceptionUtils.getMostSpecificCause(e).getMessage());
      }
```